# MySQL Subquery returns more than 1 row in WHERE Clause

Tags: mysql

im trying to figure out how can i execute my query with more than 1 row in my where clause without using the in() and any() because my current database does not support those functions. currently i have this query

```
select crack_id 
from gndmeas 
where timestamp = (select distinct timestamp 
                   from gndmeas 
                   where site_id='agb' 
                   order by timestamp desc limit 10
                  );
```

the subquery consist of

`+---------------------+
| timestamp           |
+---------------------+
| 2017-01-13 08:15:00 |
| 2017-01-10 07:00:00 |
| 2017-01-06 08:30:00 |
| 2017-01-03 10:00:00 |
| 2016-12-27 09:25:00 |
| 2016-12-20 07:30:00 |
| 2016-12-13 07:35:00 |
| 2016-12-09 08:10:00 |
| 2016-12-06 07:40:00 |
| 2016-12-02 07:00:00 |
+---------------------+`

And i want to do a select query with those data for the where clause. is it possible to execute without using the any() and in() functions of mysql?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try using `EXISTS`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use join.

```
select a.crack_id from gndmeas a join (select distinct timestamp from 
    gndmeas where site_id='agb' order by timestamp desc limit 10) b 
    on a.timestamp=b.timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this using join

```
select a.crack_id 
from gndmeas a 
inner join 
(select distinct timestamp 
                   from gndmeas 
                   where site_id='agb' 
                   order by timestamp desc limit 10
                  )as b
on a.timestamp = b.timestamp
```

Comment: You want an `INNER JOIN`, not a `LEFT JOIN`, here, because non matching records should be filtered off.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have two options at least.

Use a temporary table and store the timestamps in temp table first.
Do an inner join with the temp table to filter records in main table.

If mysql allows (I am not sure), use a nested table as part of the inner join.

Comment: yeah temporary table is a option but only in a case of stored procedure...user doesn't want to use sp...he wants single query

Answer (score 0):

Using left outer join to table :

```
select crack_id
from gndmeas G
left outer join gndmeas G1 on G.timestamp=G1.timestamp
where G.site_id='agb' 
order by G.timestamp desc limit 10
```

---

Distinct crack_id by group by clause:

```
select crack_id
from gndmeas G
left outer join gndmeas G1 on G.timestamp=G1.timestamp
where G.site_id='agb' 
group by G.crack_id
order by G.timestamp desc limit 10
```